# c# Bluetooth Serial Port Periodicali Not Getting Data

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bluetooth, serial-port

I have a c#/unity application which utilizes serial port to establish bluetooth connection with one device which then sends some data in real time back to the application. 
The problem is, that sometimes, it seems like totaly random, but at least once a minute, **serial port connection/data transfer speed drops dramatically,** device buffer is filled an thus data is lost. Turning wifi on makes matters even worse but predictable. When I tur on wifi data transfer speed dropps emidiately but in cca 3 seconds grows back to normal.
Tryed the same aplication on another similar computer and it is a bit better - speed dropps less often, and also ona a android device where it dropps even more often, but picks up the slack almost right away.
Are there any serial port settings or Sistem settings that should I take into account. Is there a way to solve this problem in code.

thx

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: No, it is proprietary, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Without code samples in your questions it is hard to give a good answer.

But from the sounds of it you are probably getting interference on the 2.4GHz radio frequence that your bluetooth device is on.

Wi-Fi is perhaps the biggest and most problematic one, as are other Bluetooth receivers and devices, which can interfere with one another.

Microwaves , Direct Satellite Service, 2.4GHz and 5GHz phones, wireless speakers, external monitors, baby monitors, and any wireless device that talks over a 2.4GHz radio frequency can interfere with your signal.

Things you can do.

1) work in a quite RF environment. one with out a lot of other devices communicating

2) physical materials can cause all sort of RF issues. Reflections / Collisions. Try to remove any physical barriers that you are communicating though. Stay away from Fluorescent Lighting and Microwaves ( both emit 2.4 GHz )

3) move your devices closer together

Because this is run as a virtual com port there are no Serial Port or System settings that can positively affect this. Might have more luck implementing your own bluetooth device driver.

Comment: Yes I came up with same stuff doing some reesearch and testing, so I ought to post theese updates to my question:

Comment: Through testing I found that on Android and on Windows, If I increese the ammount of data streaming through connection, device buffer fills periodically and dumps data. So It seems some sistem protocols mess whit abilyty to save received data in my computer's and my tablet's buffer for bluetooth virtual serial port. As if computer is not quick enough to receive all transmited data. If I dial down the speed of sending packets to about 150 hz or if I dial down the number of packets beeing sent in a given time the problem is gone.

Comment: also, the buffer owerflow does not happen as soon as i start to transmit data. It has some lag(30 sec at 200 hz) which also depends on the speed, but once it starts the buffer fills every two seconds.

Comment: I believe this deals with the retries that happens at the bluetooth rf layer

Comment: what do you mean by retries? ps: just deed some more testing at even slower speeds and the problem persists but is less comon. At 90 hz it happens every few minutes but it lasts just as long as at 200hz that is aproximately two seconds just a rate of bt device buffer becoming full is a bit slower ofcourse. The ammount of data transfer at 450hz is 500b/s which is 300b/s less than specified in BT hardware documentation. So I figure it has something to do with serial port buffer becoming full?